# Copying filtered range of cells from 1 worksheet to last row of another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a range of data (by using "Yes" from column L) on 1 worksheet ("2. Select Study-Specific Forms") and copy the data to the last row of another worksheet ("3. Worksheet"). I am using the code below. So far the code filters the data on the first worksheet but the data does not copy to the second worksheet.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
 Sub FilterAndCopy2()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    Dim LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long
    Dim TARGetSheet As Worksheet, TKSheet As Worksheet

    Set TARGetSheet = Sheets("2. Select Study-Specific Forms") 'Set sheet where filtered data is
    Set TKSheet = Sheets("3. Worksheet") ' Set Sheet name to copy data to

    LastRow = TARGetSheet.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the lastrow of the data to copy
    LastRow2 = TKSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' Determine the next empty row in order to paste the data


    With TARGetSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("G7", "L" & LastRow)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Yes"
        End With
    End With

     TARGetSheet.Range("G7", "L" & LastRow).Copy
     TKSheet.Range("A" & LastRow2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    End Sub
```

Comment: `Field` is relative to your AF range, so you need to include column F for starters and then use `Field:=1`.

Comment: @SJR Sorry, I am filtering by column L. I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Have you stepped through? I would guess that you don't have any Yes's in column L. Type 'Yes' in one cell in L and then try it.

Comment: @SJR everything works well until the line to copy the ranges.

Comment: Your code selects all filtered data (Column L with "Yes" + header) from the source worksheet (Range("G7 to lastrow") and copies these values successfully to the target worksheet. I did not find any problem! Your code works correctly!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpI4D.jpg

Comment: Thanks @simple-solution. It's working now. I have no idea what the issue was before.